# Triggering click event of child of element generated from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am creating a bunch of divs with buttons inside them from a list of id:s. Now, I would like to cause clicking the div to trigger a button click. I understand how to do this using refs if I only have one div, but if I have divs generated from mapping over an array I do not understand how to create the refs. How can this be achieved?

My code:

```js
class MyComponent extends Component<{}, {}> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }
  ids = [ "a","b","c" ];
  render() {
    return (
      this.ids.map(id => {
        return (
          <div id={`div-${id}`}>
            <button id={`btn-${id}`}/>
          </div>
        );
      });
    )
  } 
}
```

Comment: What's the current problem? With your current code the buttons don't show up, you can't know the id of the button clicked, what's the issue?

Comment: @Konstantin I want clicking the div to trigger the click event of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an useRefs helper to solve this problem, but this only works with functional components.

```
function useRefs<T>(length: number): RefObject<T>[] {
    const refsHolder = useRef<RefObject<T>[]>([]);
    const refs = refsHolder.current;
    for (let i = refs.length; i < length; i++) {
        refs[i] = createRef<T>();
    }
    refs.length = length;
    return refsHolder.current;
}
```

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    const refs = useRefs(ids.length);

    return (
      ids.map((id, i) => {
        return (
          <div ref={refs[i]} id={`div-${id}`}>
            <button id={`btn-${id}`}/>
          </div>
        );
      });
    );
}
```